# Function in R similar to month.abb for the sole 1st letter of the months?

Tags: r, function

Is there a function similar to `month.abb` in R that would display the first letter of each month?
Eg month.abb returns 'Jan', 'Feb' ... I would like the sought function to return 'J', 'F', ...

Comment: `month.abb` is not a function. It is a character vector.

Answer (score 9):

The month.abb object is not a function but rather a vector. This is the requested analog:

```
short.mo <- substr(month.abb, 1,1)
```

You can see the other inbuilt constants with:

```
?Constants
```

Answer (score 8):

```
R> month.abb
 [1] "Jan" "Feb" "Mar" "Apr" "May" "Jun" "Jul" "Aug" "Sep" "Oct" "Nov" "Dec"
R> substr(month.abb, 1, 1)
 [1] "J" "F" "M" "A" "M" "J" "J" "A" "S" "O" "N" "D"
R>
```

Just wrap this in a function.

Answer (score 3):

This is another way that indexes the abbreviations by name.

```
abbreviate(month.name, 1, strict=TRUE)
#  January  February     March     April       May      June      July 
#      "J"       "F"       "M"       "A"       "M"       "J"       "J" 
#   August September   October  November  December 
#      "A"       "S"       "O"       "N"       "D"
```